# Add points onto box plot

Tags: plotting, charts

I am trying to create a diagram like this: [image]

But I am struggling to do so, I have tried the following

```
data1 = Table[i, {i, 0, 10, 1}]
data2 = Table[i, {i, 0, 20, 2}]
BoxWhiskerChart[{data1, data2}]
BoxWhiskerChart[{data1, data2}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Point[data1]}]
```

But the get the following results

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Epilog` take points as `{x0,y0}` not the one you provided `{y0,y1,...}`

```
BoxWhiskerChart[{data1, data2}, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], 
   Point[Table[{i, i}, {i, 0, 20, 1}]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot produce your plot with MMA 11.3

Answer (score 4):

Numbers `1` and `2` are adhoc

```
{data1, data2} = 
  Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[μ, 1], 
    50], {μ, {0, 3}}];
BoxWhiskerChart[{data1, data2}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], 
   Point /@ {Transpose@{ConstantArray[1, Length@data1], data1}, 
     Transpose@{ConstantArray[2, Length@data2], data2}}}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

You can add some noise to `x` coordinate.

```
{data1, data2} = 
  Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], 1], 
    40], {\[Mu], {0, 3}}];
BoxWhiskerChart[{data1, data2}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], 
   Point /@ {Transpose@{ConstantArray[1, Length@data1] + 
        RandomReal[{-0.05, 0.05}, Length@data1], data1}, 
     Transpose@{ConstantArray[2, Length@data2] + 
        RandomReal[{-0.08, 0.08}, Length@data2], data2}}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a custom `ChartElementFunction` that combines the built-in functions `ChartElementData["BoxWhisker"]` and `ChartElementData["PointDensity"]`  to add points:

```
ClearAll[cef]
cef = {ChartElementData["BoxWhisker"][##], EdgeForm[], FaceForm[None], 
    ChartElementData["PointDensity", 
      "PointStyle" ->  Directive[EdgeForm[Black], PointSize[Large], 
        Darker[Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"]]]][##]} &;
```

Using this with the example data in OP:

```
BoxWhiskerChart[{data1, data2}, ChartStyle -> "Pastel", ChartElementFunction -> cef]
```

[image]

If you want to put the points at the centers of the boxes, you can use

```
ClearAll[cef2]
cef2 = {ChartElementData["BoxWhisker"][##], 
         PointSize[Large], Darker[Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"]], 
         Point[Thread[{Mean[#[[1]]], #2}]]} & ;

BoxWhiskerChart[{data1, data2}, ChartStyle -> "Pastel", ChartElementFunction -> cef2]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can combine `ChartElementFunction`s to render data points as lines:

```
ClearAll[cef3]
cef3[t_ : .15] = {ChartElementData["BoxWhisker"][##], EdgeForm[], 
        FaceForm[None], Thick, Darker[Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"]] ,
        ChartElementData["LineDensity"][{#[[1]] + {t, -t}, #[[2]]}, ##2]} &;

BoxWhiskerChart[{data1, data2}, ChartStyle -> "Pastel", ChartElementFunction -> cef3[]]
```

[image]